# Serial port stops receiving data after random amount of time

Tags: serial, arduino-nano

EDIT: Things I have tried so far:

1. Increasing the baud rate, but this didn't make any difference as it still continued to stop receiving data after random amount of time.
2. I tried testing one sensor and reducing the sketch to something that only prints in a sketch. I can get the sketch to work up to 2 sensors where it prints the results continuously. 3 or 4 sensors and I get the issue mentioned.

Link to the VL53L4CD library: https://github.com/stm32duino/VL53L4CD

Datasheets:

https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-vl53l4cd-time-of-flight-distance-sensor.pdf

https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/vl53l4cd.pdf

---

I'm currently working on a project where I need to measure distances at two different points using distance sensors (I'm currently using VL53L4CD laser distance sensors). However, this project requires a high sampling rate of 100Hz. To achieve this, I have 4 distance sensors arranged into 2 sensor sets. Each sensor set consists of 2 distance sensors (So for example, sensor set 1 consists of distance sensor 2&3 and sensor set 2 consists of distance sensor 1&4) and I would alternate between reading each sensor set.

This seemed to work at first, I did get a new distance reading every 8ms. However, the serial port stops receiving the distance readings after a very random amount of time. Sometimes the serial port stops receiving new data after 5 seconds, sometimes 30s, sometimes 60 and even 180s.

I'm not sure what's causing this issue what I can do to fix it. Any help is appreciated
(I'm using the Arduino Nano 33 IOT)

Thanks!

Here is my code below:

```
// Included libraries
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// Libraries required for VL53L4CD sensors
#include <vl53l4cd_class.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// Definitions
#define DEV_I2C Wire
#define SerialPort Serial

// variables
int alternate = 0; // Variable used to alternate between sensor sets

// Components.
VL53L4CD sensor_vl53l4cd_1(&DEV_I2C, 2); // xshut pin of distance sensor 1 connected to pin 2
VL53L4CD sensor_vl53l4cd_2(&DEV_I2C, 3); // xshut pin of distance sensor 2 connected to pin 3
VL53L4CD sensor_vl53l4cd_3(&DEV_I2C, 5); // xshut pin of distance sensor 3 connected to pin 5
VL53L4CD sensor_vl53l4cd_4(&DEV_I2C, 6); // xshut pin of distance sensor 4 connected to pin 6

/* Setup ---------------------------------------------------------------------*/

void setup()
{
  // DISTANCE SENSOR SETUP
  // Initialize serial for output.
  SerialPort.begin(9600);
  SerialPort.println("Starting...");

  // Initialize I2C bus.
  DEV_I2C.begin();

  // Configure VL53L4CD number 1
  Serial.println("Configuring distance sensor 1");
  sensor_vl53l4cd_1.begin();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_1.VL53L4CD_Off();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_1.InitSensor();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_1.VL53L4CD_SetI2CAddress(0x40);
  sensor_vl53l4cd_1.VL53L4CD_SetRangeTiming(10, 0);

  // Configure VL53L4CD number 2
  Serial.println("Configuring distance sensor 2");
  sensor_vl53l4cd_2.begin();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_2.VL53L4CD_Off();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_2.InitSensor();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_2.VL53L4CD_SetI2CAddress(0x42);
  sensor_vl53l4cd_2.VL53L4CD_SetRangeTiming(10, 0);

  // Configure VL53L4CD number 3
  Serial.println("Configuring distance sensor 3");
  sensor_vl53l4cd_3.begin();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_3.VL53L4CD_Off();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_3.InitSensor();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_3.VL53L4CD_SetI2CAddress(0x44);
  sensor_vl53l4cd_3.VL53L4CD_SetRangeTiming(10, 0);

  // Configure VL53L4CD number 4
  Serial.println("Configuring distance sensor 4");
  sensor_vl53l4cd_4.begin();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_4.VL53L4CD_Off();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_4.InitSensor();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_4.VL53L4CD_SetI2CAddress(0x46);
  sensor_vl53l4cd_4.VL53L4CD_SetRangeTiming(10, 0);

  // Start Measurements
  sensor_vl53l4cd_1.VL53L4CD_StartRanging();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_2.VL53L4CD_StartRanging();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_3.VL53L4CD_StartRanging();
  sensor_vl53l4cd_4.VL53L4CD_StartRanging();
}

void loop()
{
  // Read results from sensor set 1
  if (alternate == 0){ 
    VL53L4CD_Result_t results2;
    VL53L4CD_Result_t results3;

    // Read results from sensor set 1 (Sensors 2 and 3)
    sensor_vl53l4cd_2.VL53L4CD_ClearInterrupt();
    sensor_vl53l4cd_2.VL53L4CD_GetResult(&results2);
    sensor_vl53l4cd_3.VL53L4CD_ClearInterrupt();
    sensor_vl53l4cd_3.VL53L4CD_GetResult(&results3);
    
    Serial.print("Distance 1-1 = ");
    Serial.print(results2.distance_mm);
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("Distance 1-2 = ");
    Serial.print(results3.distance_mm);
    Serial.println(" ");
    
    alternate = 1; // Change value so sensor set 2 is read in the following loop
  }
  
  // Read results from sensor set 2
  else if (alternate == 1){ 
    VL53L4CD_Result_t results1;
    VL53L4CD_Result_t results4;

    // Read results from sensor set 1 (Sensors 1 and 4)
    sensor_vl53l4cd_1.VL53L4CD_ClearInterrupt();
    sensor_vl53l4cd_1.VL53L4CD_GetResult(&results1);
    sensor_vl53l4cd_4.VL53L4CD_ClearInterrupt();
    sensor_vl53l4cd_4.VL53L4CD_GetResult(&results4);
    
    Serial.print("Distance 2-1 = ");
    Serial.print(results1.distance_mm);
    Serial.println(" ");
    Serial.print("Distance 2-2 = ");
    Serial.print(results4.distance_mm);
    Serial.println(" ");
    
    alternate = 0; // Change value so sensor set 2 is read in the following loop
   }
   Serial.println(millis());
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with the VL53L4CDs, but for us to help you, do you mind linking the library that you've used in the post (and a link to the datasheet wouldn't hurt either)? Also, how does adding sensors help with the sampling rate? My hunch here is to say that you might be overflowing your I2C buffer, but I say test one sensor first, then a set of sensors, and IF that works alright, I'd start looking at two sets again and thinking about a more sophisticated flow control implementation. Do you know how much data each sensor (not set!) provides per reading? Also, try increasing the baud rate.

Comment: You might increase the baudrate so the serial buffer is less likely to overflow. Does it work without all the printing (use a LED for debug-blinking)?

Comment: Adding to @datenheim's comment: With 9600 baud you can transmit at most a bit less than 1000 bytes per second. With your sample rate of 100 Hz equaling a period of 10 ms, only 9 to 10 characters per sample are possible. -- A virtual serial connection via USB is much faster, though. The set baudrate matters only, if at least on one end a real serial line is involved. Using your PC and the Arduino built-in USB module, this is not the case, AFAIK.

Comment: Anyway, since you have no timing control in the provided sketch, I don't see how a serial buffer can overflow. All printing methods should block if their buffer is full. This way, your loop is timed by the speed of the serial transmission.

Comment: To make the problem smaller, reduce your sketch to something that only prints in a loop. If this runs long without problems, it is not the printing. Then do the same with only the sensor reading. [Edit] your question and add the findings, please.

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies and suggestions. @Nick, regarding the sampling rate of each sensor, each sensor has a maximum sampling rate of 100Hz. However at this high of a sampling rate the readings are quite inaccurate. The idea is to set the sensor to operate at a slightly lower frequency to increase the accuracy and by using two sets of sensors, I can read one set of sensor while the other set is measuring, therefore increasing the sampling rate while maintaining the accuracy (at least that's what my FYP supervisor suggested). I have also edited my post to include what I've tried so far.

Comment: Right now I suspect it could be because the USB port on my laptop cannot provide the required amount of current. I've read somewhere that the USB port on laptops only provide 100milliAmps? According to the datasheet, the peak current for a sensor can reach a maximum of 40mA. Could it be that this is why I can only use a maximum of two sensors before the problem manifests itself?

Comment: @JinYuan I doubt it's the laptop, since usually USB ports can provide up to 500mA, which should be plenty for your Arduino and the sensors. I'm not sure what's exactly going on at the moment, but your control flow should be a bit different; you can either use STM's VL53L4CD_CheckForDataReady() function or actually instantiate interrupts for all 4 sensors and process them as sets on a set interval. I don't think of 100 Hz as a high sampling rate as your loop probably runs at 100 times faster than that...well, or at least, could, as I don't know if those functions are blocking are not.

Comment: @JinYuan You can also use Adafruit's library as well and you could also try powering the a set of sensors (two sensors) from a different source than your laptop. If you  have a logic analyzer,  you could put that up just to see how the data transfer is happening when you have all 4 hooked up at the same time.

Comment: @NickS. I tried powering all of the sensors using an external source and this seems to fix the problem. I was receiving all of the distance readings consistently and the serial port did not stop receiving data.

Comment: @JinYuan sounds good, you should post your own answer then! Also, it does depend on the USB port of the laptop on how much power it can provide - some indeed are limited to only 500-750 mW (or 100-150 mA), while other can provide up to 1.5A (charging ports). Still a bit weird you saw the issue as you saw it, since the Nano 33 should be pulling on average around 50-60, if not about 100 mA just by itself (which depends on whether you are using BLE/BT/WiFi and how), but hey, if it works it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried powering all of the sensors with an external power source and this seems to solve the issue, I got consistent readings from all the distance sensors and the serial port did not stop receiving data. It might have been the USB port on my laptop that was causing these issues.